# Why can't we use C++ for web development?

Tags: c++, web-applications

Why can't we use C++ for web development?. I have been asking this question for a long time but i can't figure out the reason.

Comment: You **can** use C++ for web development.

Comment: You can!

See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737324/experiences-using-wt-c-framework/1756686#1756686

Comment: in visual studio you can only use VB or C# with asp.net @OliCharlesworth

Comment: Don't use Visual Studio, then.

Comment: @Paula: But ASP.NET is not the only framework for web development.  If you meant "Why can't C++ be used with ASP.NET?", then you should have asked that.  But use the search function, that question is already covered.

Comment: @PaulaShenouda Who told you that you can only use Visual Studio for web development.

Comment: You **can use C++** with http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt toolkit (for Web). And you can also use Ocaml with http://ocsigen.org/ and you can also use http://opalang.org/ and FastCgi web applications can be coded in C++, Ocaml, Haskell, C, etc....

Comment: If you want an answer to this question then I'd suggest you avoid using the [c++] tag and rephrase it to something like "Why isn't C++ commonly used".  C++ programmers are understandably a bit allergic to why-cant-it-do-that questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can! There just isn't as many web based frameworks. Facebook is one example of using C++ on a website.